# How to combine two vba codes?

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to combine (run) two different vba functions in one sheet. How to do that?

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
'Updateby Extendoffice 20161123
    Dim rgTable As Range
    Dim rgData As Range
    Dim xColumn As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rgTable = Range("mydata")
    With rgTable
        Set rgData = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
        If Not Application.Intersect(ActiveCell, rgData.Cells) Is Nothing Then
            xColumn = ActiveCell.Column - .Column + 1
            If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then
                .AutoFilter
            End If
            If ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(xColumn).On = True Then
                .AutoFilter Field:=xColumn
            Else
                .AutoFilter Field:=xColumn, Criteria1:=ActiveCell.Value
            End If
        End If
    End With
    Set rgData = Nothing
    Set rgTable = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

AND

```
Public blnToggle As Boolean
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick _
    (ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
'Updateby Extendoffice 20161123
    Dim LastColumn As Long, keyColumn As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim SortRange As Range
    LastColumn = _
    Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    keyColumn = Target.Column
    If keyColumn > LastColumn Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Cancel = True
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, keyColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    Set SortRange = Target.CurrentRegion
    blnToggle = Not blnToggle
    If blnToggle = True Then
        SortRange.Sort _
        Key1:=Cells(2, keyColumn), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    Else
        SortRange.Sort _
        Key1:=Cells(2, keyColumn), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
    End If
    Set SortRange = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Source:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4258-excel-click-cell-to-filter.html
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4259-excel-click-on-header-to-sort.html

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post you code.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you take two functionalities into one. Imagine that you have `Code1` and `Code2` and you want to build up `Code1AndCode2Together`:

```
Public Sub Code1()
    Debug.Print "I am code 1"
End Sub

Public Sub Code2()
    Debug.Print "I am code 2"
End Sub
```

What you should do is to check what these codes are doing and to unite them together. In general, it should look like this:

```
Public Sub Code1AndCode2Together()
    Debug.Print "I am code 1"
    Debug.Print "I am code 2"
End Sub
```

Or like this:

```
Public Sub Code1AndCode2Together()
    Code1
    Code2
End Sub
```

In your case - simply copy and paste would probably not work, but its a good start. Then try to understand what the codes are doing and try to achieve it.