# Combine two vba codes into one

Tags: excel, vba

i'm new to vba and excel also,i created a database in excel and these two codes are essential for my project to work.. i want to run these vba codes in the same time, can you help me merge the code and make it work, please? i tried by myself but nothing worked.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Dim Item As String
Dim SearchRange As Range
Dim rFound As Range

'Don't run the macro if:
'Target is not a single cell:
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
'or Target belongs to the A1.CurrentRegion:
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1").CurrentRegion) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Avoid the endless loop:
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Looks for matches from the here first:
Set SearchRange = Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)

Item = Target.Value

'Clears the Target:
Target.Value = ""

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SearchRange, Item) > 0 Then
'There's a match already:
    Set rFound = Columns(1).Find(What:=Item, After:=Cells(1, 1) _
            , LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
            , SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
'Adds one to the Quantity:
        rFound.Offset(0, 2).Value = rFound.Offset(0, 2).Value + 1

Else

'Writes the value for the Barcode-list:
Range("A" & SearchRange.Rows.Count + 1).Value = Item

'Looks for the match from sheet "Inventory" column A
    With Sheets("Inventory")
        Set rFound = .Columns(1).Find(What:=Item, After:=.Cells(1, 1) _
                , LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
                , SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        On Error GoTo 0

            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
'Writes the Product Name and puts 1 to the Quantity column:
                Range("B" & SearchRange.Rows.Count + 1).Value = rFound.Offset(0, 1).Value
                Range("C" & SearchRange.Rows.Count + 1).Value = 1
            End If
    End With
End If

'Enable the Events again:
Application.EnableEvents = True



End Sub
```

and the second one:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column <> 3 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
With Target.Offset(0, 3)
.Value = Now
.NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of ways to combine two codes. Probably the best way is to rewrite everything, but it could be that there is no need or no time or no skills for that. Take a look here for some example - [How to combine two vba codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45370502/how-to-combine-two-vba-codes).

The laziest method, I can think of is simply mimicing the `Worksheet_Change()` events, passing the target to another private sub:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

    FirstCode target
    SecondCode target

End Sub

Private Sub FirstCode(ByVal target As Range)
    Debug.Print target.Address & " from FirstCode()"
End Sub

Private Sub SecondCode(ByVal target As Range)
    Debug.Print target.Address & " from SecondCode()"
End Sub
```

Comment: cant seem to make it work, can you help a brother out please?

Comment: @user12513810 - if both the events work independently, then use their code by copy and paste and replace it in the `FirstCode()` and the `SecondCode()` - https://gist.github.com/Vitosh/2b0ccd300db89fcda80938d0057fa502 If they do not work independently, but there is another error, then you need to ask another question, explaining what does not work. Have fun. It could be that the `FirstCode()` should be `SecondCode()` or vice versa, based on business logic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Vityata. Well, the code dont have any errors but..the date changes only if i modify the cell manually:( i tried switch calling codes but didnt work. What i wanted to do is when i scan a barcode and matches in column A then write in column c "1" and in another column the date.

Comment: I can support you with some $, i know is best to learn by myself to do it but unfortunately i have to implement this Asap..

Comment: @user12513810 - "the date changes only if i modify the cell manually:( i tried switch calling codes but didnt work." - What date? This looks like something new. Advice - take 1 screenshot of the excel data (change it, before putting it online) and explain what are you trying to achieve in a new question.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mystake. So, this is my worksheet https://ibb.co/LZM1b3Z
First code, example, cell a2 is "123" when i type somewhere in the sheet(example K2) "123" then thext "123" matches to A2 and it adds "1" to the qty column in this case C2.

Comment: @user12513810 - if you put the screenshot in a new question and explain everything you have tried so far, I guess there would be a quick and nice answer. I am afk now, sry.

Comment: Sorry, i wanted to write full post but i was busy and i couldnt edit after 5 minutes.
I'm sorry, my mystake. So, this is my worksheet https://ibb.co/LZM1b3Z
First code, example, cell a2 is "123" when i type somewhere in the sheet(example K2) "123" then thext "123" matches to A2 and it adds "1" to the qty column in this case C2.
Code 2: what i wanted it to do: when in Qty Column(C2) some cell is filled with "1" then in Date Column(F) to show the date when Qty row was filled with "1"
As i said second code only works if i type manually "1" and not by searching the barcode with the first code.

Comment: You can close the question, it's solved, thank you!

Comment: @user12513810 - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers